# How to apply css hover on multiple elements

Tags: css, hover

Hi I'm working on simple hover with only css. I'm curious if it's possible to apply one hover to multiple html elements. Here is my example:

```
.work-cart{
    z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    left: 200px;
    opacity: 0;
    background: #fff;
    padding-right: 45px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: right;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
    -o-transition: all: 0.8s ease;
    transitions: all 0.8s ease;
}
.f:hover > .work-cart{
   left: 220px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.g:hover > .work-cart{
   left: 220px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.h:hover > .work-cart{
   left: 220px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Is there any option to asign the hover for .f .g and .h at once ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
.f:hover > .work-cart, .g:hover > .work-cart, .h:hover > .work-cart{
   left: 220px;
   opacity: 1;
}
```